# How to clear text fields when tab is changed?

Tags: ios, uitextfield, tabview

Hello I have a tabbed application.

It's two calculators. However when I change the tab and go back to it, the data that I entered into the text field remains the same. How do I clear it?

Comment: Clear the data in `viewWillDisappear:` of `ViewController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this for clear textfield add this line in your `viewDidUnload` or `viewWillDisappear` method

```
   yourtextfield.text=@"";
```

Hope this code is useful for you.